# How to get GET (query string) variables in HTTP on Node.js?

Tags: node.js

How can i get the variables from query string in Node.js just like we get them in $_GET/$_POST in PHP?

Here is my code, I have passed parameters through XMLHttpRequest. but i dont know how to get parameters. Please give me any suitable solution. I want to insert values in database.

**server.js**

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    url = require('url');

var db = require('../db');

http.createServer(function(request, response){

var url = require('url');
var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);
var query = url_parts.query;

console.log('Name: ' + query.name);

}).listen(8001);
```

**index.hjs**

```
function calling()
{

xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:8001/name=user_name&cell=01234-1234567", true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
       string=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
}
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**output**

```
Name: undefined
```

Comment: query string is after `?...` your url is invalid. correct it to `http://localhost:8001/?name=user_name&cell=01234-1234567`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you request wrong URL.
Should be

```
http://localhost:8001/?name=user_name&cell=01234-1234567
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:8001/name=user_name&cell=01234-1234567
```

so `name` goes in query.

Answer (score 0):

so for node js this will work

```
app.get('/products',(req,res) => {
    if(!req.query.search){
        return res.send({
            error : 'you must provide a search term'
        })
    }
    //req.query.search is to get the parameter passed on the url
    console.log(req.query.search)
    
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).